# The 2d Ising transfer matrix and the effect of anisotropy on more general transfer matrices

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, lattice-model

The 2d Ising model has a row-to-row transfer matrix that can be written suggestively as
$$T = e^{\tau \sum_i \sigma^z_i \sigma^z_{i+1}} e^{ \lambda \tau \sum_i \sigma^x_i}$$
where $\tau$ and $\lambda$ are functions of  $K_x$ and $\bar{K}_y$ (coupling in the $x$ direction and dual coupling in the $y$ direction).

$\tau$ is a parameter that I will call the anisotropy, and the $\tau \to 0$ limit gives the usual connection between the 2d classical Ising model and the 1d transverse field Ising model.

There is a small miracle that seems to happen in this model, induced by Kramers-Wannier duality. The phase boundary of the model **is independent of** $\tau$, corresponding to the $\lambda = 1$ line.

---

Suppose I modified the transfer matrix by adding more kinds of $\sigma^x$ terms, like some $\sigma^x_i \sigma^x_{i+1}$ terms with small coefficients.

$$T = e^{\tau \sum_i \sigma^z_i \sigma^z_{i+1}} e^{ \lambda \tau \sum_i  (\sigma^x_i + \frac{1}{10} \sigma^x_i \sigma^x_{i+1})}$$

Will the resulting phase boundary between the paramagnetic and ferromagnetic phases again be independent of $\tau$ (i.e. the phase boundary is just $\lambda=\lambda_c$ for some appropriate $\lambda_c$)? I'd be surprised if this were true, but it would be nice if it were.

If the phase boundary is not independent of $\tau$, is it possible to start at some point $(\lambda_0, \tau_0)$ that is in the ferromagnetic phase, and *leave* the ferromagnetic phase of the model by shrinking $\tau$ at fixed $\lambda_0$?